# ASP.NET object tag and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i m using object tag on my .aspx page

```
<object data="collapsibles.htm" height="400" width="300" />
```

in data attribute of object tag i refer the other HTML page on that HTML page one image that call the JavaScript function:

```
<img src="" alt="ipl" style="border: none" onClick="Cal()">

function Cal() {
    alert('hi All');
    var i = $("#txtMail").val();
    alert(i);
}
```

Here 'txtMail' control is on my aspx page. I access it in my HTML page but it give it  JvaScript error: 'undefined'.

My question is: how i can access this control on my HTML page?

Comment: Are you providing the correct ID of the control txtMail? If you are using Master Pages or if you are placing this control, for example inside of the GridView, you should rather use txtMail.ClientID in the code behind.

Comment: their is no master page used here my control is <input type="text" id="txtMail" value="abc" /> this control in my aspx page and trying to acces my html page this page refer by the object tag in aspx page  <object data="collapsibles.htm" height="400" width="300"  >
                </object>

Answer (score 0):

Have such code instead:

```
var i = parent.document.forms[0].elements["txtMail"].value;
```

You must use `parent` to refer to the parent page.

ASP.NET might also generate different ID and name, check the HTML source of the .aspx and see what is the ID and name of the input field.